# How exactly does DQN learn?

Tags: machine-learning, python, reinforcement-learning, dqn, openai-gym

I created my custom environment in `gym`, which is a maze. I use a `DQN` model with `BoltzmannQPolicy`.
It trains fine with the following variables:

- position of the agent
- distance from the endpoint
- position of the endpoint
- which directions can it move to

So I don't give it an image or anything. If I train and test it in the same environment (the same maze, without changing the position of walls) it can solve it easily. But if I introduce it to a completely different environment (maze) without the training then it doesn't know what to do. I don't know if the problem is with my code, or `DQN` is just for solving the same environment.

Which algorithm should I use instead?

Answer (score 4):

The way you have set your DQN up, it is designed to solve just one maze at a time. It has not (and cannot) learn to solve mazes in general, because it has no access to data about the layout of the maze, and a basic DQN agent has no capability to memorise layout seen so far.

You *could* view the training process as general algorithm for "solving the maze". That is, given a new maze, you can take your written agent, run it for a while in training mode and it will produce a policy that solves that maze. You may be able to tune or adjust the algorithm so that it does it the most efficiently in terms of time or number of steps. It will not be able to do so as well as a hard-coded maze-solving algorithm, because DQN and Q-learning is a very generic learning algorithm that takes no advantage of consisent logic seen in mazes.

If you want to train a more generic maze-solving agent, this becomes a harder problem to solve using reinforcement learning, but it is achievable. There are two key - and linked - assumptions of the theory behind Q learning that you would need to address before you could make a general maze solver that coped with variations such s moving the walls, but without needing to be re-trained:

- The [Markov property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property) is assumed for the state variables, which means that the state description contains all the relevant information about future state transitions and rewards. Without some way to know where the walls are, or at least note the position of walls it has seen before, the agent does not have access to a state representation with the Markov property.
- There is at least one deterministic optimal policy. If you are intending to withold information from the agent (and not give it capabilities such as memory in order to construct missing information), then there may not be a deterministic optimal policy.

So it is possible to use reinforcement learning to teach an agent about solving mazes in general, and gain the ability to attempt to navigate out of a new unseen before maze. If that is of interest to you, you need to first decide what capabilities and knowledge about the environment the agent is allowed to observe. E.g. what specifically interests you about writing a maze solver?

Which approaches you could use to make a more general maze solver depends critically on how you want to frame the problem. For instance it is entirely valid to give the solver an image of the maze as input if you want the agent to learn to solve mazes in a similar manner to a human solving a printed puzzle.

There is one common factor that you will need for training a more generic maze solver - you will want to train on many example mazes taken from the population of all possible mazes. Training on just one maze as an example will typically be about as successful as training a supervised classifier or regression task on one example. Adding many more mazes, or better a maze generator, and training on many of them is likely to make training time much longer than before.

Comment: Okay, so first of all thank you for both of you the answer.
As far as I understand I can use the same learning algorithm (DQN, Boltzmann Q Policy, Adam optimizer) but I need to introduce new mazes for example every 3 episodes?

Comment: @Marci You will also need to (1) decide what it is you want the agent to learn and (2) ensure the state data - or agent capabilities - are correct for what you want it to learn. The state data you supply at the moment is not enough to train a generic maze solver using basic DQN. I explain this in the answer - if there are any parts of the answer that you do not understand, please say and I may be able to clarify

Comment: I understand that I must change the input of the neural network to the image of the maze in order to make the agent able to learn what I want it to. I also understand that I have to provide another maze for every episode to "generalize" the problem. But do I have to change anything else in the algorithm (except that I think I'll need to add more hidden layers and neurons.) like the policy?

Comment: @Marci If you add the image as input and run multiple mazes in training that should be enough. Be prepared for it to take much longer to learn this more challenging task

Comment: @Neil: Why his state formulation is not enough? I have trained successfully with agent position, goal position, empty/space around the agent and directional encoding to the goal in maze environments. For sure he can use images as well but the larger the image usually the slower the training. Also it depends if someone wants interpretable features or no.

Comment: @Constantinos Because the state is clearly non-Markov for the OP. I would suspect that there is some difference between OP's maze and your setup or approach. Perhaps the non-Markov parts of your state are less important with respect to your training goals. I don't know, I have not seen either your or OP's environments in detail, but I would expect there are some significant differences which explain your successful result

Comment: @Neil: I was about to edit my answer :) You are correct about the non-Markovian state. I was thinking that if maze configuration gets quite complex you will need LSTM with these features but I am not 100% sure. The reason for this is that the agent still will have goal direction and location as inputs and training with gradually increasing complexity of the maze it will have a general sense of where to go. Then agent's myopic sight will probably help it to select empty tiles towards the goal location.

Comment: From my experience, for NOT very complex mazes it works fine (I havent tested in very complex mazes). However, image input simplifies everything.

Comment: @Marci: As Neil explained you will need to create code in order to generate different maze configurations procedurally. You can start with empty space and walls surrounding the space. Then start adding blocks of wall in the empty space with some rules (e.g. no more than 2 blocks together and always maintain an open path to the goal). If you go with the maze images as inputs and use CNNs then the network will pick up the color of the walls and associate it with places that it cannot go. It will generalize to more complex configurations of the maze.

Comment: @Constantinos: I agree a LSTM might be another approach that the OP could take, that could train a generic maze solver that remembered and used a summary of path so far. I did not want to suggest that though because it is quite advanced and I think that OP needs to consider the goals of the agent more carefully, because "solving a maze" is actually a broad category of problems where choosing the right approach starts with defining what problem you really want to look at

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that you need to do is to start your agent and the goal/end at a random (non-overlapping) location. You can try your setup initially with an empty grid (no walls). If DQN learns, your set up is good and you can start introducing obstacles into the grid. Gradually, the agent will start associating the end location inputs as something rewarding and will learn to navigate.

Things to consider (thus my suggestion to run your algorithm first in a 10x10 empty grid with random initial locations):

- Input feature space: Should better be at the same scale.
- The Boltzmann's policy temperature should anneal throughout training in order to explore at the beginning (DQN will collect it in the memory buffer) and exploit later on.
- In the maze scenario, random locations especially ones that the agent and the goal are quite close in space, will help DQN to "realize" the rewarding target soon enough. Therefore, starting with 0/few obstacles with random initial locations for all entities on the grid will act as a form of curriculum learning for your agent.